# How to multiply each numbre from a list by each number from the same list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to multiply each number from a list by each number from the same list and print the result of each operation:

```
list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
```

So it would be

```
1 * 1
1 * 2
...
...
2 * 1
2 * 2
...
...
3 * 1
3 * 2
```

and so on until each number is multiplied by each number from the same list..

I know this is completely wrong but it's what I got so far lol:

```
def table():

  list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
  num = len(list1)
  while num >= 1:
    for numero in list1:
      numero = numero * (num -1)
      print(numero)
      num = num -1
      
table()
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You realize your values are strings, right? Are you trying to repeat the string, or compute the numeric multiple? Either way, you'd pair them up using `itertools.product` with a `repeat=2` argument.

Comment: I'm looking for the numeric multiple, I just removed the double quotes from the numbers and got this: 
`9
16
21
24
25
24
21
16
9
0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in li:
    for j in li:
        print(f'{i} * {j} = {int(i)*int(j)}')
    print('')
```

I don't think this is efficient but it gets the result you want.

```
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
1 * 4 = 4
1 * 5 = 5
1 * 6 = 6
1 * 7 = 7
1 * 8 = 8
1 * 9 = 9
1 * 10 = 10

2 * 1 = 2
2 * 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 * 5 = 10
2 * 6 = 12
2 * 7 = 14
2 * 8 = 16
2 * 9 = 18
2 * 10 = 20
....
```

Comment: many thanks this is perfect, I just don't know one thing, what is that "f" for? in the first print?

Comment: f-string is used for formatting to use variables inside the print statement you can read more about it in the new documentation

Answer (score 2):

You could try with `itertools.product` too, as @ShadowRanger said in the comments:

```
ls = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

import itertools 

product=list(itertools.product(map(int,ls),repeat=2))

for i in product:
    print(f'{i[0]}*{i[1]} = {i[0]*i[1]}')

#Try this, in case you only want the result of the product:
#
#product=list(map(lambda x: f'{x[0]*x[1]}\n',product))
#print(*product)
```

Output:

```
1*1 = 1
1*2 = 2
1*3 = 3
1*4 = 4
1*5 = 5
1*6 = 6
1*7 = 7
1*8 = 8
1*9 = 9
1*10 = 10
2*1 = 2
2*2 = 4
2*3 = 6
2*4 = 8
2*5 = 10
2*6 = 12
2*7 = 14
2*8 = 16
2*9 = 18
....
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
my_list = list(map(int, ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]))
new_list = [number_n * number_m for number_n in my_list for number_m in my_list]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```